# Mode in probability distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, mode

From what I know that mode is most frequent occurring value e.g. in

```
[1, 4, 51, 14, 12, 14, 2]
```

Mode is 14 because it occurs twice and most frequent.

However, in probability distributions, I learned today that mode is the peak value that is maximum. Why is that a mode? Is it a new definition of mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When talking about *continuous* probability distributions, the notion of frequency ceases to exist, and we start talking about the *density* of a function since the interval between a value $x$ and $x + \epsilon$ is arbitrary to any  $\epsilon > 0$. Other way to think about this is that in a continuous space there are no well-defined way to group our observations (for instance, Bernoulli can only take 0 or 1; Multinomial K, any number from 1 to K; whereas a Normal(0, 1) can take any value from $(-\infty, \infty)$.

Since the space is continuous, we have no frequency, but only the *density* of a distribution around a point. Thus, we define the mode as the point(s) in the distribution with greatest density.

The takeaway is: Notion of mode for discrete distribution $\nRightarrow $ Notion of mode for continuous distributions.